# Barycenters and convexity

Tags: curves, line-integrals, centroid

**Background**

Let $c(t):[0,1]\mapsto\mathbb{R}^2$ be a curve with the following properties

1. $c(t)$ is closed;
2. $c(t)$ is symmetric with respect to the horizontal axis;
3. $c(t)$ is contained in the rectangle $\mathcal{R}\triangleq[0,1]\times[-1,1]$;
4. $c(t)$ interpolates the points $[0\,\,1]',[0\,\,-1]',[1\,\,0]$.

Now define the barycenter of $c(t)$ as
\begin{equation*}
\bar{c} \triangleq \frac{\int_0^1 c(t) \lVert\dot{c}(t)\rVert \text{ d}t}{\int_0^1 \lVert\dot{c}(t)\rVert \text{ d}t}
\end{equation*}
by symmetry, the barycenter $\bar{c}$ is located over some point of the horizontal axis, say
\begin{equation*}
\bar{c}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\bar{x} & 0
\end{array}\right]'
\end{equation*}
for some $\bar{x}$. Clearly, since the curve is inside the rectangle $\mathcal{R}$, the value of $\bar{x}$ is in $[0,1]$. I'm wondering if we can say something more about $\bar{x}$.
Consider the following limit curves shown in the picture. Let $\bar{x}_i$ be the horizontal component of the barycenter $\bar{c}_i$ associated to the curve $c_i$. We have
\begin{equation*}
\bar{x}_1 = 0 \qquad \bar{x}_2 = 1/3 \qquad \bar{x}_3 = 1/2
\end{equation*}

[image]

**Questions**

1. Can we say that for any $c(t)$ with the previous properties hold $\bar{x}\in[0,1/2]$?
2. Can we say that if $\bar{x} \geq 1/3$ then the curve $c(t)$ is convex, if $\bar{x}< 1/3$ then the curve is concave?